# Voltage Translation

Tags: mosfet, isolation

back in electronics after 7 years and found that nothing is in my bio-disk gifted by god.

now, i have a motor system that i want to make sure, no one cut the cable. apart from the 24volt motor power line (via h-bridge for fwd/rev movement) i also added 2 cables, one carrying volt (24v) to the end of it and other as return...

```
24v ----------------|
                    | motor
return -------------|
```

now, this surely brings back the 24v back to me from motor, and i can measure the presence of it and can say, no one "cut" my cables. but since i want to check via microcontroller, how exactly i can do it? (I did it using relay as an isolator, translating 24v to 5v. now i wanna do it with an n-fet). All i need is uC have to see 5v in a pin of it, when 24v is present.

Note: uC and the hbridge are two boards, 2 PSUs, commonly grounded by tying GND togather.

---

[image]

Now please tell me, is this acceptable?? MCU will see HI when switch ON and LOW when switch OFF.

Comment: If you can tell us what you want to achieve with that signal in uC, I think we'd be able to suggest more convenient ways for you. For eg, In case you strictly need it for some programming stuff, you'd need to have scale down voltage and detect both polarities. But if you just want indicating LED, there are easier ways. Also, in which section you need to detect cuts... after or before H-Bridge or both sides of H-bridge?

Comment: "Nothing is in my bio-disk gifted by god" makes zero sense.

Comment: @JYelton I think he is just trying to say his brain remembers nothing.

Comment: The option C is a good method i feel for me. Except that can i use a mosfet instead of an opto coupler?? I know it's a again a stupid question... just to be sure...

enter image description here

Now please tell me, is this acceptable?? MCU will see HI when switch ON and LOW when switch OFF.

Comment: You could use a FET as long as you don't violate VGS (max) for the FET you use (which is typically near +/- 20V)

Comment: seems so... MosFET or optocoupler (due to price/cost issue) and not the zener due to safety of isolation (for which opto-coupler is used). Now, from 24V to gate of mosfet, should I use a series resistor 10k or it should be same as stated here before in image, the 10k in parallel to Gate and GND?? I am actually looking for the best option...

Answer (score 1):

**Three options**

**A)** Voltage divider:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc4uFV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**B)** Linear regulator:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1YNUM.png)</sup>

**C)** Isolated interface using an optocoupler:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQj8Yx.png)</sup>

Comment: The option C is a good method i feel for me. Except that can i use a mosfet instead of an opto coupler?? I know it's a again a stupid question... just to be sure...

enter image description here

Now please tell me, is this acceptable?? MCU will see HI when switch ON and LOW when switch OFF.

Comment: You can use a MOSFET, but if you don't need isolation, why not just use A) or B)?

Comment: Using any sort of common ground or power bus is not TRUE isolation.  With solution A), the zener provides over-voltage protection.  With B), the regulator accepts up to 35 Volts, also has it's own built in protection, and cost $0.12.  One generally uses a transistor when one needs to provide a higher current signal from a lower current source, which is not the case here...

Comment: A) is a good way and cheaper. But if Zener fails, i mean gets damaged for some reason, then it may just fire the MCU.

B) Is nice, but it will heatup the board and itself as 24v - 5v is a lot of heat.

C) is practically isolation and yep, the best in my eyes except of my MOSFET concept, which also gives a kindof isolation. MOSFET in SMD will save some space in PCB than 4N25. But not significant space...

Note: Common ground is not total isolation, but i have no way, actually there will be 2 PSU, one for 24V and other for 12V as AUX. Both via a reverse back feed protection will make 5V

Comment: Since it will have a dual PSU, hence there will be common ground, but the purpose is only confirming that the cable of the motor (for which the 24v is) not cut by some person (a wire will be passed from pcb to motor and come back again) for motor line presence by the MCU. That's what is the actual purpose...

Comment: @Mishu - If both the 24 Volt and 5 Volt power supplies must share a common ground, then you are correct that the optocoupler won't provide complete isolation.  It would, however provide over voltage protection, including any high voltage transients that might be introduced due to the switching current in the adjacent motor feed wires.  Your MOSFET could also fail into a short just as the zener diode could.  You could always add another 5.1 Volt zener on the output, and I would hope that you already have some over-current protection on the 24 Volt feed, like a fuse or resistor...

Comment: @Mishu - Also keep in mind that the zener would likely short to ground, still protecting the input to your microcontroller, while the MOSFET could short the gate into your output....